# Adding a pre-loader on click .load() function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, pagination

I am having a problem using .load() in jquery

This is my current code

```
jQuery(document).on('click','#Pagination a', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    var nxtPage =  jQuery(this).attr('href');
    window.history.pushState('obj', 'newtitle', nxtPage);
    jQuery('.preloadswitch').load(link+' .the-categories').fadeIn('slow');      
});
```

This actually works, however I need for it to fadeIn + pre-loader when getting the content then disappears if the content is visible

Can I make this a ajax where it has a "beforeSend" or "success" function? Thanks

**This is not working also**

```
jQuery('.preloadswitch').load(link+'.the-categories',function(response,status,xhr){
    if(status == 'sucess'){ 
        jQuery('.preloadswitch').removeClass('addpreloader');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery('.preloadswitch')
    .fadeIn('slow')                // Fades it in.
    .addClass('addpreloader')      // Adds the pre-loader class.
    // Loads the content.
    .load(link+' .the-categories', function(){
        // Removes the pre-loader class once AJAX is completed.
        $(this).removeClass('addpreloader');
    } );
```

Comment: Hi Sally CJ, it triggers and error (TypeError: jQuery(...).fadeIn(...).addClass(...).load(...).always is not a function)

Comment: Sorry about that. Please try again with the updated code.

Comment: Hi @Sally CJ, its working now, thank you so much, your a life saver :-)

Comment: I'm glad it helped you, and all the best. =)